# save and display for files in user profile in Moodle

Tags: php, file-upload, plugins, moodle

I'm trying to create a moodle profile field plugin for file upload.
my `edit_field_add` in `field.class` is:

```
function edit_field_add(&$mform) {
    $maxlength = 1024*1024;
    $fieldtype = $this->field->param2;

    /// Create the form field
    $mform->addElement('filepicker', $this->inputname, format_string($this->field->name), null,
               array('maxbytes' => $maxlength, 'accepted_types' => $fieldtype));
    $mform->setType($this->inputname,PARAM_FILE);
}
```

This shows and saves file correctly but
Saves a number in `data` field of plugin (e.g. `766686554`)
How can I find the URL to the uploaded file to make a link to it by `display_data` in 'field.class` ?

**EDIT**

I'm saving the file by this:

```
function edit_save_data_preprocess($data, &$datarecord) {
    $draftitemid=file_get_submitted_draft_itemid($this->inputname);
    if (empty($entry->id)) {
        $entry = new stdClass;
        $entry->id = 0;
    }
    $context = context_user::instance($this->userid);
    file_save_draft_area_files($draftitemid, $context->id, 'profile_field_fileupload', $this->inputname,$entry->id);

    return $draftitemid;

}
```

But draft still exists and I cant find how to retrieve saved file!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have saved the file after the form has been posted  -http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms#filepicker

Then you can use the File API to retrieve the file(s) - http://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API#Serving_files_to_users

eg to display links to all files for the plugin:

```
$out = array();

$fs = get_file_storage();
$files = $fs->get_area_files($contextid, $pluginname, $pluginfolder);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filename = $file->get_filename();
    $url = moodle_url::make_file_url('/pluginfile.php', array(
         $file->get_contextid(),
         $pluginname,
         $pluginfolder,
         $file->get_itemid(),
         $file->get_filepath(), $filename)
    );
    $out[] = html_writer::link($url, $filename);
}

$br = html_writer::empty_tag('br');
echo implode($br, $out);
```

Comment: I'm saving file by `file_save_draft_area_files`; but draft still exists and I can't find out how to find the result file! please check my edit